# Face Recognition using Flutter

Tags: api, face-recognition

I am trying to build an application where one of my modules is to use face recognition to verify the users including some other verification methods as well (which aren't important to discuss here for now).

I am using **Flutter** to develop the application. I am facing an issue while working on this module. I am not finding any SDK or library which we can implement using flutter to get the **face recognition** done. I knew about only two APIs regarding this which are:

1. [Firebase ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces)
   But the issue with this is it doesn't provide any solution for face recognition.
2. [Microsoft Face API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/concepts/face-recognition)
   The issue with this is that it doesn't provide any SDK for the flutter. Client SDKs are available only for **Python** and **.Net**.

**My Question**

Is there any other face recognition API available that I can use with flutter or are there any alternative methods to use MS Face API with **Flutter**?

Answer (score 0):

I used the PHP API for Microsoft Face API and sent requests using PHP.
The PHP Rest API samples are provided on each topic. e.g. [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523a)

A face API reference list is provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/identity-api-reference). You can navigate to a specific API and find the relevant code info there.